# How do I select for something with a colon with Zend_Db_Select?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db-select

I have a query where I need to select text with a colon inside, basically it looks like this:

```
$select = $this->db->select()
    ->from('table')
    ->where(sprintf('tag = "%s"','foursquare:venue=12345'));
```

Now when I run this, I get the exception "Invalid bind-variable name :venue" which is obviously because the Mysqli adapter doesn't allow bind variables. The thing is now - I don't even want to use this as bind variable, I want to fire that query pretty much exactly like this. How can I prevent Zend_Db_Select from trying to do it's thing? There is an open issue for the framework ([#1398](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-1398)) which is really old and unfixed, so I guess most people find a workaround. Probably a really simple one and I'm just too stupid to see it.

Any hints?

Comment: Have you tried using `->where(new Zend_Db_Expr("tag = foursquare:venue=12345"));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using sprintf? You're overriding the built-in quoting mechanism that would normally handle this situation for you:

```
$select = $this->db->select()
    ->from('table')
    ->where('tag = ?', $tag);
```